# Spliting Json data into array<string> columns

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have many json arrays stored in a table like this:

```
{"p_id":
   {"id_type":"XXX","id":"ABC111"},
   "r_ids":[
      {"id_type":"HAWARE_ABCDA1","id":"dfe234fhgt"},
      {"id_type":"HAWARE_CDFE2","id":"sgteth5673"}
   ]
}
```

My requirement is to get data in below format:

```
p_id , p_id_type ,r_ids (array string), r_id_type (array string)
```

Ex: `XXX,ABC111,[dfe234fhgt,sgteth5673],[HAWARE_ABCDA1,HAWARE_CDFE2]`

I am able to get the whole set in exploded format but how to generate array

My current query:

```
select p_id
      ,p_id_type
      ,get_json_object(c.qqqq,'$.id') as r_id
      ,get_json_object(c.qqqq,'$.id_type') as r_id_type
from
(
select p_id
      ,p_id_type
      ,qqqq
    from
    (
      select 
        get_json_object(a.main_pk,'$.id_type') as p_id_type
       ,get_json_object(a.main_pk,'$.id') as p_id
       ,split(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a.r_ids,'\\}\\,\\{','\\}\\;\\{'),'\\[|\\]',''),'\\;') as yyyy
      from
      (
        select 
          get_json_object(json_string,'$.p_id') as main_pk
         ,get_json_object(json_string, '$.r_ids') as r_ids
        from sample_table limit 10
       ) a
    ) b lateral view explode(b.yyyy) yyyy_exploded as qqqq
   )c
```

Can anyone help me what wrong I am doing? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `JsonSerDe`, it will be more easy to solve complex data types.
I am giving here small example, you can solve by using this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_json (
  p_id struct<id_type:string,
              id:string,
              r_ids:array<struct<id_type:string,
                                  id:string>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<path>/your_file.json'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE table_json;
```